# Laravel guard login

Tags: laravel

I am a bit stuck using a custom login for my Admin users.

I pref to use another Model for my admin just to make sure everything is separated. I did see a lot examples to made a guard for the login. So watching some tutorials and read some articles I gave it a go and got stuck.

For my Admin I made a second guard.

```
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        //'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

using providers:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Users\Admin::class,
    ]
]
```

And yes my Admin model is located as namespace App\Models\Users;

In the login controller I changed:

```
Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));
```

to:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));
```

Without the guard it work/ Get a Auth with a User model. But I want the admin guard to work to get a Admin model.

Right now, nothing happend. Not a error or a Auth user.

Anyone here that see what I am doing wrong here?

P.S. I cleared config:cache etc a lot already.

UPDATE:
When I changed the default Gaurd to 'admin' and login without specifying a guard. I get a Admin model back. So something goes wrong when I use the `Auth::guard('admin')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the user that is logged in you should also specify the guard.

So if you log-in with a guard like this:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));
```

You should also retrieve the user with the guard like this:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()
```

Comment: One tip: if your're using the `auth` middleware in your routes, you can specify `auth:admin` in order to automatically use the "admin" guard when calling `Auth::user()`.
For example you can do `Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('auth:admin')->group(...);` and all your Controllers used by the /admin routes will always use the "admin" guard.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `auth()->guard('admin')`. I hope it helps

Comment: it did not. Thanks tho